# How to retrieve the master NFT edition from the printed edition

Tags: metaplex, nft, metaplex-js, nfts

I'm looking for the master edition of an NFT from a printed edition.

For instance, if I have this NFT (https://explorer.solana.com/address/2ceqd5xghCeJ6gTX8Rf27w8HJkXYRjs644TXBXebi5kT?cluster=devnet), is there a way to find it's master edition (https://solscan.io/token/Hv8e8qsbBwBpZicyuxTredkSq5rkGaofLAND9984dQTS?cluster=devnet).

Answer (score 1):

An Edition Account has a parent attribute (in its account data) pointing to the Master Edition, see [source](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/overview#printing-editions).

To get from the Mint Account to the Edition Account you can use the seed described [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/accounts#edition).